# Browsing to phpMyAdmin Fatal Error: Failed opening Message.class.php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

Today when I turned on my XAMPP I started Apache and MySQL. When I browsed to `localhost` my site worked.

But when I visited `localhost/phpmyadmin` I got this error in my browser:

> Warning: require_once(./libraries/Message.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in G:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Error.class.php on line 16`page
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './libraries/Message.class.php' (include_path='G:\xampp\php\PEAR') in G:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Error.class.php on line 16

I can't start phpMyAdmin, but Apache is working properly. Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Well, does `G:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Error.class.php` exist?

Comment: Yes,  G:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Error.class.php exist

Comment: the problem is not if `G:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Error.class.php` exists or not, of course it exists since the error came from it. This file is trying to include another file: `G:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Message.class.php` do this one exists?

Comment: No ,  G:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Message.class.php  , this file does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the comments:

Your phpmyadmin install is corrupted since one file is missing, try to download this file for your specific version of phpmyadmin.

Or (recommended option) download the entire phpmyadmin new version at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin

Comment: ok thanks sir for your valuable time . I will do what you recommended.