# Cannot open phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

Cannot open phpmyadmin and got this error?

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   './libraries/relation.lib.php'
>   (include_path='/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium:.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php')
>   in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php
>   on line 123

Can anyone please help to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Check if file is present in XAMP folder [Fatal error php XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47779515/fatal-error-php-xampp). if this don't solve your problem try re installing